# Hide popup when clicked

Tags: javascript, popup

I use the script below to create a popup. How can I hide the popup when the user clicks it?

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('_visited=1') == -1) {
    var delay_popup = 1000;
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('parent_popup').style.display='block'", delay_popup);
    var date = new Date;
    date.setDate( date.getDate() + 1 ); // текущая дата + 1 день
    document.cookie = '_visited=1; path=/; expires=' + date.toUTCString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add onclick event like this:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('_visited=1') == -1) {
    var delay_popup = 1000;
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('parent_popup').style.display='block'", delay_popup);
    var date = new Date;
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1); // текущая дата + 1 день
    document.cookie = '_visited=1; path=/; expires=' + date.toUTCString();

    document.getElementById('parent_popup').onclick = function() {
        this.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks much DFSQ ,  can you please tell me one more think,  I want Iframe to be in blank, but it does not work in  div,  for example href="site" target="_blank" however.  iwant that happened with this simple javascript code, is it possible please? if it does. let me know . PS love  you.